# Did I set up mongodb correctly?

Tags: mongodb, mean-stack, database

I'm trying to create a MEAN stack, but I don't seem to be able to get it to work. I have installed mongodb but when I type `mongod` I get an error on the output that reads:

```
I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
```

What does this mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: are you trying to access the mongo shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely reason is that the permissions on the mongod binary are not set to allow your account to execute it. You can confirm this by using sudo mongod, assuming you're using Linux or a Mac. If that works you can change the permissions for mongod so you don't have to time sudo every time.

Check out this post if you still have questions, as your error is referenced a few times: https://gist.github.com/adamgibbons/cc7b263ab3d52924d83b. Hope that helps.

Comment: In addition to @heidesw answer, if you are on Windows, open command prompt with admin privileges by right clicking on the cmd icon and click "run as administrator"